# Select record, and if it has children, select the newest child instead

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
element_id, element_parent_id
```

Records are:

```
1, null
2, 1
3, 1
4, null
```

So, visualization might look like:

```
1
  2
  3
4
```

The question is, how to select for:

```
form_id
3
4
```

...in other words: how to select parent if there is no children, or the newest child if those children exist. So far I managed to select for:

```
1 and 4
2 and 3
1, 2, 3 and 4
```

Comment: Generally, we also want you to show us what you have tried before we give you an answer.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I tried dozens of guesses using joins, left joins, subqueries, variables and IN(). So, since I don't really know how to solve my problem, don't expect me to copy here all of my unfortunate queries. And stop putting everyone to "lazy-people" box. Help instead.

Comment: Do you only have two levels (parents and children)? Or could you have more? If so, what of a parent that has children, but also a grandparent and so is a child itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be a bit more useful I'll explain my reasoning to arrive at the final query (at the bottom).

You are selecting *two different entities* from the *same* table, so you need a `JOIN` of the table against itself; this will give you parents and children.

But children may not be there and so it will have to be a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
 SELECT p.id, c.id AS cid
 FROM yourtable AS p 
 LEFT JOIN yourtable AS c ON (c.parent_id = p.id);

+------+------+
| id   | cid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 | # This one...
|    1 |    2 | # ...and this one must be grouped, and 3 taken.
|    3 | NULL | <-- this must be ignored because it's a child
|    4 | NULL |
|    2 | NULL | <-- this must be ignored because it's a child
+------+------+
```

Now to refine, we see that we need to ignore children in the "parent" role and to this purpose we add `WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL`. "Real" children have a parent, and will then be skipped.

> **Note**: this is the point where we would need to do something more complicated if we had a multi-level hierarchy. If we only wanted the
>   bottom level, i.e. the "true" children (ignore those parents that have
>   themselves a parent), we could for example run a *second* `LEFT JOIN`
>   to get the *grand*parents, and impose that the grandparent's id be not
>   NULL. This is only true for third level and greater grandchildren. Or
>   we could get the children *of the children* and impose that they have
>   NULL id, i.e. they don't exist; this is only true for the *bottom* or
>   last-level children. Other requirements could call for yet another set
>   of bounds.

Then you want the "top" child in relation to a parent id, and this calls for a `GROUP BY`, which will yield the desired result *when children are there*, or NULL when there aren't.

```
 SELECT p.id, MAX(c.id) AS cid
     FROM yourtable AS p 
     LEFT JOIN yourtable AS c ON (c.parent_id = p.id)
     WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL
     GROUP BY p.id;

+------+------+
| id   | cid  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |
|    4 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

In *that* case we see the information is in the *parent*-side column (`id`).

And to choose which, I would resort to a `SUBSELECT`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cid IS NULL THEN id ELSE cid END AS wanted
FROM ( 

    SELECT p.id, MAX(c.id) AS cid 
    FROM yourtable AS p
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS c ON (c.parent_id = p.id)
    WHERE p.parent_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY p.id 
) AS x;
```